# Turnkey Bitcoin test clone for demonstration purpose

Tags: wallet, open-source

So I'd like to demonstrate a blockchain based digital currency within my firm. For various reasons, I can't just use bitcoin (or of course I would).

I also can't distribute pc exes, hence the requirement for a web based wallet. Security does not need to be paramount. There does not need to be a competition for mining although mining does need to be a component (ie there will probably be just one miner running on one cpu / low priority).

Is there an open source web wallet and counterpart configurable mining system ? I took a quick look at coinpunk but I'm not sure that is still supported / running (last update almost a year ago, website offline?).

All suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you that what you are looking for probably does not exist. I did the same search recently.

I was in talks with a large company and all they wanted to hear was the Blockchain and how they could use it. They asked to have their own Blockchain -i.e. altcoin. You are probably in a similar situation.

The best course of action here -in my opinion- is to try to convince them that a Blockchain that they will create is just a more expensive and much more complex version of a Database. And the altcoin will be nothing more than records on that expensive, complex and possibly insecure database.

In my case I was able to convince them -somewhat- but the response was:

> We still can't use Bitcoin because of internal politics and PR risks

In the end, I convinced them to use Bitcoin testnet :) I suggest you do the same.

Bitcoin testnet is the closest thing to what you are looking for.

It's not Bitcoin, it doesn't have real value and there are online and mobile wallets built for it. You can also play around with mining on testnet.

Just call it Testnet instead of Bitcoin Testnet and hope that they will get more comfortable with Bitcoin in time.

Comment: Although testnet would solve a few problems, it still means that the client needs to install some software somewhere and also although these tokens have no real value, they might be used for demonstrating voting and kickstarter-esque funding. Any dev would easily be able to obtain a fair few testnet coins and then rig the system. It really has to be standalone :-/

Comment: there are web wallets for testnet. Your only option is to fork Bitcoin and get your own testnet up and running. Then fork an open source wallet. It will be messy. Sorry :) I don't think you're going to find a turnkey solution.

Comment: You can also look into colored coins.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the easiest way would probably be to setup a Signet (or use testnet until wider signet adoption) with a mobile wallet that supports test network(s), such as Green wallet.